# How to use modules like request when making an android apk using kivy and python?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

My kivy/python app works perfectly on windows but when I try to run the apk using buildozer I get an error that says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests` Where do I have to install the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your requirements line in buildozer.spec.